# Do NSAIDS (Ibuprofen, etc.) actually speed up healing or do they just mask pain?

Tags: injury, pain, medicine

I have a minor muscle pull in my lower back (right side). The initial pull happened Friday, but I re-aggravated it somewhat last night. I'm trying to heal this injury as quickly as possible for an upcoming tennis tournament. I've been following the advice to use mostly ice and compression during the first 48 hours, then alternating in heat thereafter. This seemed to be helping until I stressed it a bit playing tennis last night.

Anyway, I'm wondering if I should also be taking Ibuprofen. Will it speed up healing beyond just using "RICE" or just help with pain management? I mostly only feel pain when I sit in certain positions or try to bend over (say, to put on socks), so pain is not really an issue most of the time. I just want to do whatever I can to heal as quickly as possible.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It depends. With ibuprofen in particular, the anti-inflammatory properties are beneficial. Initially inflammation is important for healing an injury, but too much inflammation is detrimental. Based on that I prefer to take ibuprofen if the inflammation persists, but not immediately after getting the injury.

Pain killers can also indirectly contribute to healing. If the pain prevents you from getting adequate rest, your body can't repair itself as effectively, so if taking a pain killer helps you sleep better that could actually help you recover from the injury faster.

For your specific situation, I wouldn't expect any painkiller to be particularly beneficial. If you feel pain only in certain positions rather than constant soreness that doesn't suggest inflammation, and if you can rest without feeling pain you wouldn't get any benefit from painkillers.

I would suggest finding a massage therapist who specialises in trigger points/myofascial release. It's something you could do yourself, but given the short time frame you describe a skilled practitioner is more likely to get you the results you need by the time you need it.

If that isn't an option, I would look into buying a foam roller. Lie on it with your back, find a point that hurts and steadily roll back and forth on it for no longer than a minute. You shouldn't necessarily be looking for where you feel the pain when you bend over, but for where you feel the pain from your bodyweight on the roller. Do it on both sides, and focus on your whole back. Do this several times per day. If it's not a serious injury it should get a lot better. You could even take the foam roller to the tennis tournament and do it between matches. Any time you treat muscle issues yourself they have a tendency to keep coming back for quite some time, but the temporary relief is often enough to let you do whichever activity it is you needed to do.

Comment: Well stated on all points. +1

Comment: +1. Couldn't have asked for a better answer. I forgot to mention that I have been getting daily massages from someone who has taken some classes and is quite good though hasn't been trained specifically in trigger points/myofascial release. I like the idea of the foam roller as well. Thanks for your help!

Comment: +1 for the Foam Roller. That's been a miracle cure for my back for a couple of years now.

Answer (score 3):

Ref foam rollers.They don't work for me!
Here is my story.

I am 74 in a very good shape, I exercise regularly and I practice moderately a number of sports, including bicycling, kayaking and windsurfing in summer.

Last winter, one year ago, I had  sprained a back muscle while unsuccessfully resisting   falling on the ice on my way home. A week after,the acute pain  had subsided using Advil and cold packs. 
Four months after, however, the pain was still lingering,  although tolerable. 
I then  decided to see a doctor, because I didn't want to miss the windsurfing season( summers are very short round here!) 
The doctor  prescribed an x-ray( non-resulting) and physiotherapy treatment.

It finally healed ( so I thought) after three physiotherapy sessions.

After another 6 months, however, the muscle pain mysteriously woke up again at the same place, for no apparent reasons, although not acute.

This time, before seeing a physiotherapist again,( expensive !) I tried self-treatment in various ways: 
Voltaren Emugel was of absolutely no help.

Advil, on the other hand, did good : with only 1 pill before going to bed, the pain was gone the next morning and I applied hot packs for a couple of days.
I then felt so well  that I stopped Advil and the hot packs and I went swimming a few days after!

Unfortunately, the pain came back. 
At this point, I read your site and I got hold of a foam roller. 
Regretfully, not only it  didn't work, but it worsened my condition:

First,it is very very painful on the sore muscle when rolling back and forth with the full body weighing on it.

Second, the pain came back with a vengeance right after it and I had to go back to Advil and hot packs .

Now I think I am on my way out, but I'll be careful not to resume a full activity for a few days.

Still wonder though, why that lingering recurrent pain 
one year after!

I'll see a physiotherapist if it is still there in a few weeks.
But for the moment NO FOAM ROLLERS, I am afraid !

Franco Vivona