# Healing process

Tags: injury, health

Is it possible to speed up the healing process and if so how? For example: I have recently pulled a muscle in my shoulder and a little while after that twisted my ankle, what is the best way to a speedy recovery?

Answer (score 2):

Injury sucks and it can never heal quick enough. To let it heal completely, you will need to have patience, though.

First of all - and yes, I'm being preachy, bear with me - see a specialist. A trip to your physician is never really wasted time, even if he just tells you to slow down. In the worst case scenario you're really hurt and doing nothing can lead to much more problems. I had a broken finger some years ago. I didn't get it looked at and I can't move it as well as my other fingers now.

Listen to your physician first. If you don't like what he's telling you, get a second opinion if you must. But don't assume you know better, chances are you don't.

Now, for lighter injuries that don't need a specialist's intervention I like to follow some simple rules: Don't exercise until you are fully healed. Do not 'warm up thoroughly' and do not 'work out lightly', chances are you'll overdo it. Try not to use the injured limb in everyday activities as much (don't walk to work with a sprained ankle). Also, when in doubt, don't assume you have healed already. Better be safe than sorry, as an incompletely healed injury can quickly become as bad as on the first day.

Lastly, Some things you can do to might help speeding up recovery:

- Eat right: Don't diet. Your body needs to rebuild stuff now, don't deprive it of building blocks.
- Sleep enough: Recovery is most efficiently done during sleep. Try to get at least eight hours a day, preferably more. If you can't seem to manage that, afternoon naps might be an option.
- Try not to get sick: The flu will most definitely not speed up your recovery. Keep away from long walks in the rain, showering with an open window etc. Sounds stupid, but it happened to me once, not funny.
- Medicine: [Here's a question regarding ibuprofen](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/7134/do-nsaids-ibuprofen-etc-actually-speed-up-healing-or-do-they-just-mask-pain?rq=1) and it's effects on healing. It touches upon other medicine, too. Always consult someone who knows their stuff (general physician, pharmacist) before taking anything, though.

Comment: While I applaud your answer, the question itself is off topic for the site.

Comment: Noooooo! Ah well, I thought something like that myself, after answering...

Comment: Rest, ice it, and take anti-inflammatory tablets such as ibuprofen is the best cause of action.  Not much else